# keep me logged in JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets

How do I make "keep me logged in" box in JSP page? Looks like it has something to do with the cookie, right?

The below is my JSP code.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
${errorMessage}
${successMessage}
Please log in.
<form action="login" method="post">
    <p>
    <label>
        id
        <input type="text" name="id"/>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>
        password
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="login"/>
    </p>
<-- I AM TRYING TO PUT KEEP ME LOGGIN BOX RIGHT HERE! -->
</form>
<a href="getpass.jsp">Forgot password?</a>
<a href="register.jsp">Don't have an account?</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to make that box, but I am not sure where to go from here.

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this when you are validating your username and password.

```
String value = request.getParameter("rememberMe");
boolean rememberMe = false;
if(value != null && value.equalsIgnoreCase("on")){
    rememberMe = true;
}
if (rememberMe) {           //If your checkbox value is true
Cookie cookieUsername = new Cookie("cookieLoginUser", username);
Cookie cookiePassword = new Cookie("cookieLoginPassword",
                    password);
// Make the cookie one year last
cookieUsername.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
cookiePassword.setMaxAge(60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
servletResponse.addCookie(cookieUsername);
servletResponse.addCookie(cookiePassword);
}
```

And in your jsp page,

```
<%Cookie[] cookies=request.getCookies();
String name="",pass="";
if (cookies != null) {
     for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
       if (cookie.getName().equals("cookieLoginUser")) {
           name=cookie.getValue();
       }
       if(cookie.getName().equals("cookieLoginPassword")){
           pass=cookie.getValue();
       }
    }
}
%>
```

You can use this `name` and `pass` for your purpose.
**Updated**
And in your jsp

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe">
<label for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes you are correct. This need to be done once you have successfully logged (inside servlet).

Comment: If I have the box like this, input type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>: I do let my servlet know if the box is checked? For text input, you just do getParameter("paraeterName"), what about the check box?

Comment: You need to add name attribute to checkbox and keep it inside the form. Hence you can get the checkbox value like `on`, based on that you can perform it. `<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe"><label for="checkbox">Keep me logged in</label>` and in your servlet similar like `String value = request.getParameter("rememberMe")`

Comment: What is <% %> in JSP page? I can put these part anywhere in JSP? It doesn't look like a javascript.

Comment: Yes you are right, It is a scriptlet tag. It is not encouraged. Anyway for you to get some idea from that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43377/discussion-between-vinoth-krishnan-and-user3014926)